# LINQ and dynamic strong types

Tags: linq, list, dynamic, strong-typing

I try to find some references on LINQ with dynamic added strong types, static I have as in example:

```
        var rowColl = _data.AsEnumerable();
        var json = (from r in rowColl
                    select new
                    {
                        name = r.Field<string>("name"),
                        id = r.Field<int>("id"),
                    }).ToList();
```

Now where I am interested in if its possible to make "name" and "id" dynamic added on runtime as the information is available in the DataTable "_data", I think there is a simple solution for this however cant find any references on this

Comment: Nope. Compiler creates an anonymous class for you at compile time. It is possible to create new types at runtime though. See `Reflection.Emit` namespace.

Comment: and a not simple solution, I am pretty sure that I am not the first one who has this issue

Comment: `Reflection.Emit` does take some practice to get good at. Decidedly not for beginners.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19283503/difference-between-key-and-key-and-value-versus-value-in-list-and-dictionary This brings it a little more closer to the answer

Answer (score 0):

It's better practice to avoid using "var" as your type when possible. It looks like rowColl is of type IEnumerable<DataRow>. If that's true, then I would look to see what you can use in the DataRow class (see [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.aspx)).

Given that rowColl is actually IEnumerable<DataRow>... If the columns are always going to be in the same order, then you could just do something like r[0] and r[1] in your select statement, i.e.

```
var json = (from r in rowColl
            select new
            {
                name = r[0], // Where 0 is the index of the "name" column
                id = r[1],
            }).ToList();
```

If it complains at you for type-safety, then you could use int.Parse() to cast the string to an int and use the .ToString() extension on your columns instead.

Comment: Not related to the question